# Create a new variable using observations and labels

Tags: stata

I have a variable that looks like this:
[image]

I want a new variable that multiplies the labels with the frequency, so for example the first row would be 1*70,105=70,105, and 2 would be 2*36,377=72754 and so on. I want my new variable to look like this:

[image]

​​​​​​​How can I do this?

Comment: 70105 and the like are not "labels" in any Stata sense, but that just be terminology rather than misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it you have at least 119167 observations. The "at least" refers to the possibility of missing values, not `tabulate`d by default.

You don't say whether you want these values in the same observations or in a much reduced new dataset. If the former, then consider this (noting that 3845 * 4 = 15380).

````
clear 
input apple freq
1 70105 
2 36377
3 8840
4 3845
end 

expand freq 

tab apple 

bysort apple : gen new = apple * _N

tabdisp apple, c(new)

----------------------
    apple |        new
----------+-----------
        1 |      70105
        2 |      72754
        3 |      26520
        4 |      15380
----------------------
```
````